# Is this proof for Corollary 29.4. Munkres Topology correct?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

The followings are from Munkres' Topology:

[image]

After a long time I still can't prove Corollary 29.4. based on the information from Corollary 29.3. and Theorem 29.1. especially when they are irrelevant (note that Y-X must be a single point).

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, suppose $X$ is homeomorphic to an open subspace $A$ of a compact Hausdorff space $Y$.  By Corollary 29.3, $A$ is locally compact, and hence so is $X$.  Also, $A$ is Hausdorff since any subspace of a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff, and thus so is $X$.

Conversely, suppose $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff.  By Theorem 29.1, there exists a compact Hausdorff space $Y$ such that $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ and $Y-X$ has one point.  Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, the singleton set $Y-X$ is closed in $Y$, so $X$ is open as a subset of $Y$.  Thus $X$ is homeomorphic to an open subspace of a compact Hausdorff space (namely, itself as a subspace of $Y$).

Comment: The key point that I'd forgotten: a single point is closed in a Hausdorff space. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Let me ask you the following question: Am i right that in the first paragraph of your answer you are using that $Y$ is locally Hausdorff space because it is compact Hausdorff space, right?

Comment: @ZFR: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @user200918 you don’t have to know “a single point is closed in a Hausdorff space” fact. We have defined topology on $Y$ as $\mathcal{T}_Y = \mathcal{T}_X \cup \{ Y-C| C\subseteq X$ and $C$ is compact$\}$. So $X\in \mathcal{T}_X \subset \mathcal{T}_Y$. Identity map is homeomorphism, $X \cong X$.

Answer (score 3):

The space $Y$ in theorem 29.1 should be the one-point compactification (Alexandroff extension) $X^* = X \cup \{\infty\}$ of $X$. The inclusion $X \rightarrow X^*$ is always continuous and open; $X^*$ is always compact; and it is Hausdorff if and only if $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: Sorry, but you have explained Thm 29.1 and I am struggling to understand the proof of Corollary 29.4.